# parsing nested json data - access directly to a member

Tags: html, json, parsing

I have json data like

```
data = {
    "id":1,
    "name":"abc",
    "address": {
        "items":[
            "streetName":"cde",
            "streetId":"SID"
         ]
     }
 }
```

How can i access directly to the streetName Value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is actually invalid. If you have control over the json generation, first change it to this:

```
data = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "address": {
        "items": [{
            "streetName": "cde",
            "streetId": "SID"
        }]
    }
}
```

Notice the additional braces around `streetName` and `streetId`. Then, to access `streetName`, do this:

```
var streetName = data.address.items[0].streetName;
```